# Select MySQL vs find MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

i have 2 dbs: one in mySql and one in MongoDB with the same data inside...
i do the follow in mySQL:

```
Select tweet.testo From tweet Where tweet.testo like ‘%pizza%’
```

and this is the result:

```
1627 rows in set (2.79 sec)
```

but if i exec in mongo:

```
Db.tweets.find({text: /pizza/ }).explain()
```

this is the result:

```
nscannedObjects" : 1606334,
"n" : 1169,
```

or if i exec:

```
Db.tweets.find({text: /pizza/i }).explain()
```

this is the result:

```
"nscannedObjects" : 1606334,
"n" : 1641,
```

Why the number of rows/document in mysql/mongo find is different?

Comment: Maybe the difference will become obvious when you examine the cases which were only returned by MongoDB and not by mySQL.

Comment: To see the differences between mongo result and mysql result can give an answer. Print records which aren't in the both results and observe some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the number of rows/document in mysql/mongo find is different??

There could be 1000000000000000 reasons including the temperature of the sun on that particular day.

MongoDB and MySQL are two completely separate techs as such if you expect to keep both in synch you will need some kind of replicator between the two. You have not made us aware as to whether this is the case.

Also we have no idea of your coding, server setup, network setup and everything else so really we cannot even begin to answer this.

A good answer would be to say that the reason you are seeing this is because the data between the two is different...

As for the difference between:

```
Db.tweets.find({text: /pizza/ }).explain()
```

and

```
Db.tweets.find({text: /pizza/i }).explain()
```

This is because MySQL, by default, queries in lower case I believe and MongoDB (I know) does not as such it is case sensitive (this `i` makes it case insensitive).

However about replicators, here is a good one: https://docs.continuent.com/wiki/display/TEDOC/Replicating+from+MySQL+to+MongoDB

Comment: thanks for your answer...my problem is very simple: i capture tweets to twitter and save its in mongodb and in mysql.. so i am certain that in each two dbs i have the same data..boh!!!

Comment: There must be something that makes the two different in some way so that MySQL picks that number and MongoDB picks the other, are you sure all tweets that you captured when in? If you do a diff between the MongoDB result and the MySQL result what do you get?

Comment: Thanks Sammaye..i don't know how to do a diff... and if i search things that returned few documents/rows the number is the same but is different if returned many documents/rows and see the difference is complicated.

Comment: joking aside, how would "temperature of the sun on that particular day" have an impact? MongoDB is more susceptible to heat and somehow churns out more results than expected?

Comment: @asgs hmmm, certain hardware can be more susceptible than others, if you are writing to two different dcs, one located in, like, Sweden, and another located in, let's say, KSA, that could have an impact, not a problem you would ever have to concern yourself with but could exist, in theory

Comment: @asgs as a note, if you ever are in such a case, MongoDB would be able to take the strain better due to its fsync queue

Comment: @Sammaye great to know about `fsync()`! what does MySQL use instead?

Comment: @asgs just a straight to disk queue by default, it can use a fsync queue but by default, for ACID reasons, it will just plonk it right to disk

Answer (score 1):

the mysql command

`Select tweet.testo From tweet Where tweet.testo like ‘%pizza%’`

is equivalent to MongoDB's

`Db.tweets.find({text: /pizza/i })`

I realized they both contain the same data, but in some cases the text in mysql was cut-off, so it resulted in less rows being returned.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with your SQL query `like '%pizza%'` may not pickup entries that begin with the string 'pizza' because of the wildcard on the front. Try the following SQL query to rule out any syntactical differences with the matching logic in SQL and the Regex used by MongoDB

```
Select tweet.testo From tweet Where lower(tweet.testo) like ‘%pizza%’ or lower(tweet.testo) like ‘pizza%’
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have mySQL in front of me just now so can't verify the leading wildcard behaviour described above, however this is consistent with other RDBMS so it's worth checking*

Comment: I just tested this on MySQL 5.1.63, `%string%` and `string%` find the same thing

Comment: confirm...%string% find astring abcstingabc stringfff...string% find string stringabc stringfff but not abcstring